# How does Outlook know if an MSG file has been sent?

Tags: c#, outlook, msg

If you start writing an email in Outlook and drag it from Drafts to your desktop, Outlook will open it with the Send button available and all fields modifiable.

Likewise, if you drag a received email to your desktop, Outlook will open the MSG file in read-only mode.

I am hoping to add a feature in my c# application which can read a sent MSG file and then write it back in draft mode.  So far I haven't had much luck finding any information on this.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the unsent message doesn't have any of the headers in it that would indicate it's been sent already, and the received mail has all of those headers included in the saved message. Either that, or it simply marks it as unsent when you drag an unsent message to the desktop and it packages it to be written there, and also marks the received message when it's sent to the desktop. To be certain, you'd have to ask the Outlook team at MS.

Comment: If it's in your Drafts folder, then Outlook knows that it hasn't been sent. If it's in your received folder, then Outlook knows that it's an email that you received. It's trivial for Outlook to include some status flags in the clipboard information that moves from the application to your desktop. That information would be available to the application that responds when you drop the item onto the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook looks at the `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit in the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` MAPI property (you can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - I am its author - click IMessage button for a message in one of the Outlook folders or OpenIMsgOnIStg button in case of a standalone MSG file).

Outlook would not let you modify that flag - `MailItem.Sent` property is read-only. Moreover, that bit can be set (if you are using Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi) only before the message is saved for the very first time. That limitation does not apply to the standalone MSG file - `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit can be set or unset at any time.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, its [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Sent` property is read-write. To open a standalone MSG file, you can use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` method (returns `RDOMail` object) - you can then modify the `Sent` property and call `RDOMail.Save`.